# Capture HTTP 307 redirect URL

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am making calls to the Facebook API and am trying to capture the **access token** from the response.

When I make a call to the following URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={client_id}&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token
```

I get a brief redirect to a URL which shows the **access token** if I am already logged in, or displays the FB Login Form in my browser:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token={access_token}&expires_in={time}
```

The above URL only shows for a second or two before finally being redirected to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#_=_
```

My question is, how can I capture the **access token** in the second URL?

I have been trying to capture the URL via the following method:

```
private void FBBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) {
    String urlResponse = e.Uri.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("FB URL Response: " + urlResponse);
}
```

**The problem is that the URL being picked up by the listener is the first URL to which I make a call, not the response URL which is what I am after.**

*(Please note that I have removed the access_token and client_id from the URL's for security purposes)*

***Additional Note - after doing some inspection of the request sequence in the browser, I noticed that the first response is HTTP 302, followed by a HTTP 307. The location header of the 307 Response is what I need to parse using C# as it contains the access token.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is an issue with capturing characters after a '#' symbol when using the WPF Web Browser Control. This poses a problem with access tokens as they are returned as follows in the URL:

```
#access_token='token_code'&expires_in='time'
```

This blog [post](http://aravind-microsofttech.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/facebook-oauth-authentication-for-wpf.html) covers a workaround by using the System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser instead. By adapting this technique I was able to finally parse the access token from the URL.

I hope this helps anyone else who may have run into a similar issue.